# How to pass the html character codes

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How to get the HTML character codes displayed in phyton-sphinx generated docs.

```
sign : &#64;
```

I want the above to be displayed after building the rst as following :

```
sign : @
```

but it doesn't work, I was trying it [here](http://rst.ninjs.org/?theme=nature#CnNpZ24gOiAmIzY0OyAgCgo=)

**EDIT**

I am writing a tool that will read some predefined tokens (e.g. `@package`) from the code files and then generate the rst files.  I am then using the sphinx-build to generate the documentation.
Since `@package` is already a token in my tool, I don't want to use @package as text. e.g

```
@todo Add tests cases for the @package tag
```

so I wanted to comment something like this in the code.

```
@todo Add tests cases for &#64;package tag in the code.
```

Comment: Please provide more context. Sphinx will not convert special characters, for the most part. So literally just @ should be fine, or use double-ticks around it \`\`@\`\`

Comment: @StevePiercy i have updated the question with more details, however as you have already suggested, ``@package`` is doing the trick.